# Validating multiple same attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have model `Invitation` with attribute `email`. I want to save multiple email addresses at once to db. How I can add more then 1 email addresses in form field, validate them, and save them to db if they pass validations? (without making second model)

Something like this:

[image]

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have some sort of custom validation on your model. So you have an invitation model it would have validation like

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :validate_email_csv

  # your code

  def validate_email_csv
    # iterate through email csv adding errors were necessary
    # errors[:email_csv] << 'Emails are not valid' # or custom build up string
  end
end
```

Check out the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods). You could also use a custom validator, but that can be something for you to look into.